# In Solidity, how to check whether the code is being executed on-chain or not?

Tags: solidity, view

I would like to write an `external view` function that throws when being executed on-chain, but does not throw when executing client-side. (for example when it is called through web3.js)

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I very much doubt there's a way to do this. (If there is, it's likely to be considered a bug and fixed in the future.) I'm curious why you would want this.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit 2021:** Since solidity 0.5.0, the built-in function `gasleft()` replaced `msg.gas`.

> ∀ transactions: msg.gas > 0

Check for the gas amount !

Comment: `msg.gas` was deprecated in solidity version `0.4.22`, and it no longer compiles since version `0.5.0`